# Tableau Desktop connecting to SparkThriftServer but giving permission error in reading CSV

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, tableau-api

I have tested Master/Slave same machine with Tableau also on same machine. Tableau connected to SparkThriftServer and worked fine. Could read the CSV file also.

Now I tried same but this time real spark cluster on a remote machine. It connects but the moment I fire a query to read a csv, it give permission error.

Remote machines are Ubuntu machines and the user id is sudo

In Tableau, I am using SSH credentials for SparkThriftServer's Authentication

Correct me if am wrong anywhere

Answer (score 0):

What I realised is this that all the Slaves need to access the file that I am trying to point to read in Tableau in SQL Query. I was firing an SQL in of Tableau. This path was for a data file present only in Spark Master.

The Spark Slaves didn't have access to that data file

Considering I didn't install Hadoop, I used SSHFS to mount one data folder that I created on Spark Master's

Now all slaves can access that folder on their local machine as it is mounted like a local folder.